# new instead of Object.create

Tags: javascript, object

Normally I'm doing it that way:

```
$.fn.MYPL = function (options) {
   return this.each(function () {
      myplg = Object.create(MYPL);
      myplg.init(options, this);
   });
};
```

**Object.create** is not supported in IE6, IE7, and IE8. I just realized, that I can replace **Object.create** with [**new**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) like:

```
var g = new Graph();
```

But I have no idea.. How to change my plugin definition?

I've tried:

```
var myplg = new MYPL();
```

But it's not working. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where and how is `MYPL` defined?

Answer (score 2):

You can [polyfill `Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) so that you can use it in IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the [*MDN* polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) did not support anything with a properties object, so I wrote a slightly more complete implementation which will at least let you set *value* and *warn* about others if there is a console available and also throws the right kind of error messages.

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = (function () {
        function _Object() {}

        return function(proto, props) {
            var o, k, d;
            if (proto !== null && typeof proto !== 'object')
                throw new TypeError('Object prototype may only be an Object or null');
            _Object.prototype = proto;
            o = new _Object();
            for (k in props) {
                if (typeof props[k] !== 'object')
                    throw new TypeError('Property description must be an object: ' + props[k]);
                for (d in props[k])
                    if (d === 'value')
                        o[k] = props[k].value;
                    else
                        if (console && console.warn)
                            console.warn('Object.create implementation does not support: ' + d);
            }
            return o;
        };
    }());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create(MYPL)` sets object prototype. For constructor-based approach you can try the following code:

```
function MYPLConstructor() {}

for (var key in MYPL) {
     MYPLConstructor.prototype[key] = MYPL[key];
}

var myplg = new MYPLConstructor();
```